# Drop multiple columns when column name has space pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col3  Col4
11         10      s     1
12         22      g     10
```

If I find the column names and Do

```
<<df.columns
>>Index(['Col 1', 'Col 2' , 'Col3', 'Col4'])
```

If I want to remove `Col 1` and `Col 2` from my df , then what to do:

```
df.drop(['Col 1, Col 2'], axis=1)
```

I am getting error:

```
KeyError: "['Col 1, Col 2'] not found in axis"
```

EDIT:

It works with below syntax

```
 df.drop(['Col 1', 'Col 2'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need remove columns with spaces:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('\s')]
print (df)
  Col3  Col4
0    s     1
1    g    10
```

But maybe space is not space, you can test it by `ord`, for space got `32`:

```
a = [ord(x) for x in df.columns[0]]
print (a)
[67, 111, 108, 32, 49]
```